# Make a decreasing list from a number

Tags: oz, mozart

I need to create a decreasing list of all whole numbers between X and Y (inclusive).

I am trying this:

```
declare
local
   fun {Dec From To}
      From | {Dec From-1 To}
   end
in
   {Browse {Loop 8 1}} % Should Display: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
end
```

The Mozart compiler shows that the code is accepted, but no Browse window opens up.

What is wrong?

Comment: And what is “Loop”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think nothing is shown because your function **Dec** is an infinite loop because you never set when to stop, and that's why the browse window is not displayed.

The function should be:

```
fun {Dec From To}
  if From == To then 
    nil
  else
    From | {Dec (From-1) To}
  end
end
```

I hope this was helpful :)